# PHP MYSQL SUBMISSIONS INTO TABLE WITH MULTIPLE FOREIGN KEYS

Tags: php, mysql

I am designing a system for an organization with different "User" Types but with same details(FirstName,OtherNames,DateOfBirth,Gender,Contact, Cell, Ward,Division, Province, and District)with each different UserType having about one or two unique additional fields eg Marital Status, etc. To avoid cases of registering say a district for every user, I have created tables(Cells, Wards, Divisions, Provinces and Districts) so that they are registered by the admin through their respective forms and the point of registering the Users, he just picks from respective drop down menus eg District: (Drop down menu with all districts in the database)... These tables for addresses are referenced by One USER_COMMON_DETAILS table... So, It fields like(Fname,  OtherNames, DateOfBirth, Gender, Contact, UserType and foreign Key fields like *Cell_IDCell, *Ward_IDWard,*Division_IDDivision,...etc! This USER_COMMON_DETAILS table is being referenced by different User tables for example Admins, Salespersons etc... I am providing UserTypes from HTML dropdown options so that I dont have to create a table for that in the database too...  However, I don't know how to submit details into my USER_COMMON_DETAILS table using PHP-Mysql, because every time I try, I don't find any records in the DB even if my forms can't complain of any errors...

What do I do???? Using WampServer... Connections successful!!!

For example, how do I register SalesMan with just one unique field "Marital_Status"???
Thanks

Comment: you might need to re structure your question, is hard to read

Comment: $a=$_POST['salesfname'];
$b=$_POST['salesothername'];
$c=$_POST['salesdatebirth'];
$d=$_POST['salesgender'];
$e=$_POST['salescontact'];
$f=$_POST['salesUserType'];
$g=$_POST['salescell'];
$h=$_POST['salesward'];
$i=$_POST['salesdiv'];
$j=$_POST['salesdistrict'];
$k=$_POST['salesmarriage'];

$id=mysql_insert_id();

$query="INSERT INTO User_Common_Details(firstName,OtherNames,dateBirth,gender,contact,userType,cell_IDcell,ward_IDward,division_IDdivision, district_IDDistrict,maritalStatus)VALUES ('$a','$b','$c','$d','$e','$f','$g','$h','$i','$j','$k')";

mysql_query ($query);

This shows no error,

Comment: I wonder how much time you'll need to get your first SQL injection attack :)

Answer (score 1):

Create separate tables for your reference tables i.e. UserType[id,user_type] and MaritalStatus[id, marital_status]. Obviously id should be a primary key.

Then add foreign key columns to your User table (user_type_id and marital_status_id).

This will be a dynamic method in case you will add some more marital status or user types.

You can query user table like this

```
SELECT user.*, userType.user_type, maritalStatus.marital_status FROM user LEFT JOIN userType ON user.user_type_id=userType.id LEFT JOIN maritalStatus ON user.marital_status_id=maritalStatus.id
```

Hope this helps.